# OutOfMemoryError in Ubuntu server

Tags: java, memory, ubuntu, out-of-memory, ram

I have a server, written in java  that working fine in Windows 7. But when I installed the same in Ubuntu, it shows out of memory error, server having 8 GB of ram and our server using only 70% of Ram, it shows out of memory error. And CPU usage is at the peak at out of memory time.

1. How can I allocate the remaining 30 % of ram to my application?
2. How can I increase the limit of memory that allocated to an application in Ubuntu?

Out of memory error does not occur in Windows, only Ubuntu. In the windows Task manager shows 100% CPU usage and full RAM usage. I wish to implement this performance in Ubuntu.

Comment: *"outOfMemory exception"*  DYM [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)?  Note that exceptions are different to errors and should be treated differently.

Comment: what is your Xmx setting? and also could you paste the stacktrace

Comment: -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms1500m -Xmx8g -server -verbose:gc

Comment: As Ajay says, please post the stacktrace and exact exception. Depending on the program, it isn't necessarily heap space that is running out; it could just as well be permgen space or even direct buffers or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that Java throws an [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html), you first need to understand why. You probably want to pick up a profiler like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net) (free) or [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) (not free) to see what's going on in memory. After that, you can decide on the appropriate action(s), like making your app more memory-efficient or changing the JVM settings to increase the appropriate memory allocation.

To get you started, if you're running out of heap space (old generation), you can adjust the maximum heap available using the JVM flag `-Xmx`. For example, `-Xmx1024m` or `-Xmx1g` will set the max to 1GB. If it's the permanent generation (PermGen), you can allocate a larger chunk of overall heap to that using the `-XX:MaxPermSize` JVM flag, such as `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`. Note that increasing the size of the permanent generation will correspondingly decrease the amount of memory available to the other heap segments.

Full details on these and other JVM memory settings can be found on the [Java application launcher page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) and the [HotSpot VM Options page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) (assuming you're using the HotSpot VM).

Comment: My JVM Settings -XX:+UseCompressedOops  -Xms1500m  -Xmx8g  -server  -verbose:gc

Comment: out of memory error is not occured in windows its only appeared in ubuntu. In the windows Tesk manager shows 100% Cpu usage and full RAM usage. I wish to implement this performance in ubuntu

Comment: If it's a Java OutOfMemoryError, Windows vs. Ubuntu is mostly irrelevant. Did you read my answer? Have you figured out why you're running out of memory, as in what type of memory, how much is allocated, and possibly what's using it all up?

Comment: *"Windows vs. Ubuntu is mostly irrelevant."*  +1 agreed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ulimit](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm) to restrict the RAM usage for desired processes.

Additionally, for `Java` applications, you can pass arguments like `-Xms` (minimum), `-Xmx` (maximum) to `java` process (M for MBs, G for GBs).